# Functions inside of an object are not working correctly - Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object

This is my first "program" or whatever you want to call it using JavaScript.

I need to modify the `avg`, `total`, and `grade` by using 2 functions: `calcAVG` and `calcGrade`. I cannot get the `calcAVG` function to work correctly. I can't figure out why the function won't modify the `avg` or `total` value. In the program, I can't modify the top 5 properties of the object (it's for an assignment).

Also the `calcAVG` function works when called in the `console.log`. So do I have some kind of syntax error?

```js
var student = {
 fullName : 'Amanda Corbin',
 scores : [90,50,88,56,89],
 avg : 0,
 total : 0,
 grade : '',
 
 calcAvg : function(scores,avg,total) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.scores.length; i++) {
   this.total += this.scores[i];
  }
  this.avg = ( this.total / this.scores.length );
  return (this.avg);
 }
 
 
  calcGrade : function(avg,grade) {
  
  if (this.avg >=90){
   console.log("grade is A");
   this.grade = 'A';
  } else if (this.avg >= 80 && this.avg <90){
   console.log("grade is B");
   this.grade = 'B';
  } else if (this.avg >= 70 && this.avg <80){
   console.log("grade is C");
   this.grade = 'C';
  } else if (this.avg >= 60 && this.avg <70){
   console.log("grade is D");
   this.grade = 'D';
  } else if (this.avg <60){
   console.log("grade is F");
   this.grade = 'F';
  }
  
  
  return (this.grade);
 }


console.log(student);

console.log(student.calcAvg());
console.log(student.calcGrade());
```

Comment: 1. no comma after `calcAvg` function 2. no closing `}` to close `student`. There's also no need for the function parameters; you're accessing the fields via `this`. And you can remove the parens around the values you're returning.

Comment: *I cannot get the calcAVG function to work correctly* - in what way is it incorrect?

Comment: @ jaromanda X I'm using notepad++ and chrome to make/view the program. When I use the console.log(student.calcAvg()); i get back 74.6 which is the correct value. I'm not sure why its not working for you. With the calcAVG function not working, the calcGrade one will not work. (i tried passing it the avg directly without the other function and had it work correctly for me).  Anywhos thank you for the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris is right in the comment above.

Your final code should look like this

```
var student = {
    fullName : 'Amanda Corbin',
    scores : [90,50,88,56,89],
    avg : 0,
    total : 0,
    grade : '',

    calcAvg : function(scores,avg,total) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.scores.length; i++) {
            this.total += this.scores[i];
        }
        this.avg = ( this.total / this.scores.length );
        return (this.avg);
    },


     calcGrade : function(avg,grade) {

        if (this.avg >=90){
            console.log("grade is A");
            this.grade = 'A';
        } else if (this.avg >= 80 && this.avg <90){
            console.log("grade is B");
            this.grade = 'B';
        } else if (this.avg >= 70 && this.avg <80){
            console.log("grade is C");
            this.grade = 'C';
        } else if (this.avg >= 60 && this.avg <70){
            console.log("grade is D");
            this.grade = 'D';
        } else if (this.avg <60){
            console.log("grade is F");
            this.grade = 'F';
        }


        return (this.grade);
    }
}


console.log(student);

console.log(student.calcAvg());
console.log(student.calcGrade());
```

Here is the output for the same on a coderpad sandbox [link](https://coderpad.io/sandbox) (Just copy-paste the above code and you can see the output.

[image]

Comment: if that were the case, how can *the calcAVG function works when called in the console.log*

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I still can't get it to work. I will ask my professor tomorrow

Comment: @JaromandaX I have attached the working output in my answer above. I hope that helps.

Comment: I didn't know that you had to call each function in order to modify the avg, total, and grade. I assumed that when you call the student object, it would run the functions inside of the object. I got it to work now! thank you for taking the time to go through it.

Comment: @AmandaCorbin No worries. Happy to help! Keep experimenting and learning 

Comment: "call the student object" - did you mean create?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a few commas and a closing `};`

```js
var student = {
  calcAvg: function(scores, avg, total) {

  }, // missing a comma here
  calcGrade: function(avg, grade) {

  }, // missing a comma here
}; // missing a closing bracket here
```

Comment: if that were the case, how can *the calcAVG function works when called in the console.log*

Comment: Sorry, didn't even check the functions. Maybe this with help https://javascript.info/object-methods

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I still can't get it to work. I didn't even realise the missing closing bracket.

Answer (score 1):

If you put your code on a editor you will see some missing parts. like `,` and `}`. Other thing is you don't need to use any parameters in those functions. you are not passing any parameters into those functions. there you use `this` keyword. that will pick the correct property of your `student` array.

```js
var student = {
 fullName : 'Amanda Corbin',
 scores : [90,50,88,56,89],
 avg : 0,
 total : 0,
 grade : '',
 calcAvg : function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.scores.length; i++) {
   this.total += this.scores[i];
  }
  this.avg = ( this.total / this.scores.length );
  return (this.avg);
 },
 calcGrade : function() {
  
  if (this.avg >=90){
   console.log("grade is A");
   this.grade = 'A';
  } else if (this.avg >= 80 && this.avg <90){
   console.log("grade is B");
   this.grade = 'B';
  } else if (this.avg >= 70 && this.avg <80){
   console.log("grade is C");
   this.grade = 'C';
  } else if (this.avg >= 60 && this.avg <70){
   console.log("grade is D");
   this.grade = 'D';
  } else if (this.avg <60){
   console.log("grade is F");
   this.grade = 'F';
  }
  
  
  return (this.grade);
 }

}


console.log(student.calcAvg());
console.log(student.calcGrade());
```